# cant return a new list in binary search python different code

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm  a beginner in python , and I am doing the binary search task, I'm trying a different code than what  it is common. My issue is that  I can't return a new binary list. In the first time the function is working as it suppose to be, but for the second time the function isn't return the new list.

### My Code:

```py
    import random, math
    
    user_choice=random.randint(0,100)
    print (user_choice)
    max=100
    number_elements=50
    number_list=random.sample(range(max), number_elements)
    sort_list=sorted(number_list)
    print (sort_list)
    count=0
    limit=int(math.sqrt(number_elements))
    
    # divide by 2 the length of the number_list
    def divide_list(sort_list):
        global count,number_elements
        number_elements=int(number_elements//2)
        count += 1
        half=len(sort_list)//2
        if user_choice <= sort_list[number_elements] :
            sort_list=sort_list[:half]
            print(sort_list)
        else  :
            sort_list=sort_list[half:]
            print(sort_list)
        return sort_list
            
    
    while len(sort_list)==0 or count <=limit:
        max /= 2
        divide_list(sort_list)
```

### Output :

```py
    99
    [5, 6, 8, 9, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 44, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 80, 81, 86, 90, 96, 97, 99],
    [48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 80, 81, 86, 90, 96, 97, 99]
    [48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 80, 81, 86, 90, 96, 97, 99]
    [48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 80, 81, 86, 90, 96, 97, 99]
    [48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 80, 81, 86, 90, 96, 97, 99]
    [48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 80, 81, 86, 90, 96, 97, 99]
    [48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 80, 81, 86, 90, 96, 97, 99]
    [48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 80, 81, 86, 90, 96, 97, 99]
    [48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 80, 81, 86, 90, 96, 97, 99]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `divide_list(sort_list)` --> `sort_list = divide_list(sort_list)` - you are not using the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning the list but you are not storing/updating it.

**Solution:**

Change the line `divide_list(sort_list)` to `sort_list = divide_list(sort_list)`.

**Explanation:**

When you are updating the variable `sort_list` inside the function before printing (the line --> `sort_list=sort_list[half:]`), it is updating the variable `sort_list` associated to that function call and not the global variable `sort_list`. So by storing the return value in the global variable (as given in my solution), your list gets updated and passes the updated list next time the function is called.

Comment: I realised after I posted that this was already answered in the comments. Sorry.